# How can I see the intermediate results of Spark shuffle？

Tags: apache-spark

I want to know what the intermediate result in Spark between shuffle write and shuffle read looks like, and how should I view it?

Comment: In Spark, intermediate results (RDDs) are not typically exposed due to the nature of Spark's execution model. Even if you try to persist the result of each transformation, it will be an expensive operation.